# How to manage image pasting from clipboard in html5?

Tags: html

On Documentum Eroom App, IE is capable of automatically uploading image from clipboard pasting whereas Firefox can't.

So I wonder if html5 supports that kind of behavior (not just drag and drop of image/file from explorer).

Update: granting access is not enough it's also about being able to handle BINARY data not just TEXT does current firefox  can handle binary I can't see it maybe it's not explicit ?

It's not about just drag and drop which is widely already implemented on many sites. It's about BINARY FORMAT CLIPBOARD MANIPULATION to save the image from the clipboard to the server without any need to save file and then drag and drop. The process to save the file somewhere is extremely daunting for user so direct uploading from clipboard is really a must time saver.

Comment: I wonder if there is any open-source implementation what works. As far as I know pasting images in Google Docs works perfectly but I am looking for something that could be used to improve any file-upload functionality, maybe even without changing the server side application.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, HTML5 has this capability and it is becoming widely implemented. You can handle events from Ctrl+V and get binary image data and do whatever you want with it.

Currently Google Chrome 13.0.782.220 works great. I have a jQuery plugin with a full demo illustrating the feature (be sure to use Google Chrome, I can't guarantee it other browsers)

http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/

As robertc mentions the Clipboard API spec is becoming standardized, so it should lead to adoption across browser soon enough.

Comment: Great sorry for the delay I checked as good answer only today that's a long time I didn't come here

Comment: Indeed, anything in Firefox front?

Comment: Someone made an updated JSFiddle version here http://jsfiddle.net/FhUwn/392/ that should work in Chrome, IE, and FF

Answer (score 8):

There is a ['Clipboard API and events'](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/) spec going through the standards process, but even if it gets implemented it's likely a user would have to explicitly enable it on a per-site basis.  For example Firefox already has methods for accessing clipboard data with JavaScript, [but they are turned off by default](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard).

Comment: granting access is not enough it's also about being able to handle BINARY data not just TEXT does current firefox  can handle binary I can't see it maybe it's not explicit ?

Comment: @user310291 Sorry, since you mentioned drag and drop I assumed you were already aware of the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) as it's [implemented in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications).

Comment: Yes but here it's not about just drag and drop which is widely already implemented on many sites. It's about BINARY FORMAT CLIPBOARD MANIPULATION to save the image from the clipboard to the server without any need to save file and then drag and drop.

Comment: @user310291 Files are files, whether they come from a drag event or a paste event, that's what the File API is for: FILES.

Comment: I thought this question was about pasting image data, (not a image  file).