# How can I read clipboard data in a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard

I am new to web development. I was looking at [Snaggy](http://snag.gy/)'s feature where you can directly paste an image and it gets uploaded to Snaggy.

I did a little research on StackOverflow and I found that it is near-impossible to read the data from clipboard.

**As a newbie, please help me understand how it can be achieved.**  :)

My references for research:
[Get current clipboard content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413036/get-current-clipboard-content)
[Read the client clipboard with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744621/read-the-client-clipboard-with-jquery)

Comment: This sounds like a dangerous, insecure, user-unfriendly feature. You should not be able to read a user's clipboard data under any circumstance.

Comment: You want to know how to get the image from the clipboard?

Comment: @JoeFrambach, even in flash/java-applets?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, sir! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472526/will-there-ever-be-an-html5-clipboard-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snaggy is using a java applet to access the clipboard. This technique doesn't work without the Java extension installed and enabled in the browser.

There is no way to read from a visitor's clipboard using JavaScript in any popular browser.

Comment: IE is "popular" among uneducated users.

Comment: @corey [Not even this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253468/get-pasted-image-from-clipboard-firefox)

Comment: @LittleChild Depends how technical you want to get. You're not accessing the clipboard the OS — you're handling a paste event. This allows for behavior similar to Snaggy, for sure, but you still can't access the clipboard if a user doesn't paste their clipboard.

Comment: ahhh .. yes, I want to handle the paste event. :)

Answer (score 1):

I remember there was a possibility to read the clipboard content in Adobe Flash.
I'm not very familiar with Flash programming, so I can't really explain how to achieve copy/paste automation, but there it is described how to [read/write clipboard data using ActionScript3.0](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS2F6A31B9-1AE6-4b23-9C12-57A33F4F0516.html).
There is also way using a library, [described in this blog](http://www.paulund.co.uk/jquery-copy-clipboard).