# What can I use to capture and upload "Copy and Paste" images?

Tags: html, image, copy-paste, plupload

Just like stack exchange has the ability to accept pasting of images I would like to implement this on my website too. I tried to search for it but I am not sure what the correct terminology is and get really strange results.

[image]

I wanted to use plupload to upload images but I am not sure how this works exactly.
What plugin can I use to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you are looking for is the "Clipboard API and events" http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/

A post that seems consistent with the fact that the paste feature does not seem to be avalaible on firefox here on stackexchange :
http://css.dzone.com/articles/paste-wasteland-or-why-onpaste

As far as I know this behavior is not implemented in plupload.

This might be of some help if you want to evolve plupload or develop your own feature :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7496598/1236044